# Adding reference assemblies to Roslyn analyzer code fix unit tests

Tags: roslyn, analyzer

I'm attempting to write a unit test to test a Roslyn analyzer code fix. Things have moved on since the introduction of analyzers and editing DiagnosticVerifier.Helper.cs is no longer the way ( https://www.productiverage.com/creating-a-c-sharp-roslyn-analyser-for-beginners-by-a-beginner )

My analyzer works on mvc ControllerBase derived types yet adding the name of the AspNetCore assemblies to the reference assemblies does not resolve the issue of my test not resolving the AspNetCore namespace includes in the test source code

```
var test = new VerifyCS.Test();
mytest.ReferenceAssemblies = test.ReferenceAssemblies.AddAssemblies( ImmutableArray.Create(new string[] { "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc"}));
```

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist
> in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

EDIT:
fixed, using:

```
mytest.ReferenceAssemblies = mytest.ReferenceAssemblies.WithPackages(ImmutableArray.Create(new PackageIdentity[] { new PackageIdentity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core", "2.2.5") }));
```

Comment: I've met similar problem, but I try to add my custom dll. It looks for me, I've tried all ways, but it doesn't work - `CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyNamespace' could not be found`. Your solution with packages doesn't work in my case, 'cos my dll isn't NuGet-package. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: EDIT: fixed by using:
`test.ReferenceAssemblies = test.ReferenceAssemblies.AddAssemblies(ImmutableArray.Create<string>(@"D:\Projects\Libs\My"));` where "My" is name of file "My.dll". So - full path, but without extension should be used.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the long syntax of `VerifyCS.Test`:

```
await new VerifyCS.Test
{
    ReferenceAssemblies = referenceAssemblies,
    TestState =
    {
        Sources = {test },
        //ExpectedDiagnostics = {VerifyCS.Diagnostic().WithLocation(0).WithArguments("xxx")}
    }, // FixedCode = "yyy", etc.
}.RunAsync();
```

You can add assemblies and nuget packages:

```
var referenceAssemblies = ReferenceAssemblies.Default
    .AddPackages(ImmutableArray.Create(
        new PackageIdentity("serilog", "2.10.0"),
        new PackageIdentity("Othe.Package.Name", "1.2.0")
        )
    ).AddAssemblies(
      ImmutableArray.Create(
        "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions")
    );
```

BEWARE: the nuget packages are recovered only from the feeds specified in  `nuget.config`, so, if you're using pacakages from an special feed, like your company's DevOps feed, you need to include it in this config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    ....
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="myCompanyFeed" value="https://mycompanyfeed.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyCoNuget/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <clear />
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

Removing the `<clear/>` is another option, but less portable.